# After editing my.cnf MySQL fails to restart

Tags: mysql, database, my.cnf

I want to edit the `/etc/my.cnf` file.

I've tried to use this as the file content:

```
[mysqld]
set-variable = max_allowed_packet=24M
set-variable = max_connections=300
log-slow-queries
safe-show-database
local-infile=0
open_files_limit=3980
```

then, I've tried to restart the `mysql` server:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql restart
```

but it failed with the following error:

```
root@server1 [~]# /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql restart
Shutting down MySQL.... [ OK ]
Starting MySQL...The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql server1.domain.com.pid). [FAILED]
```

I've read [here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1114852) that I need to replace `[mysqld]` with `[mysql]`, but he is using Percona, and I am just using a standart whm/cpanel installation, will it work too?

Comment: You need to read the error log and find out what's preventing MySQL from starting.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-log.html

Comment: FWIW, I'm not aware that `set-variable = max_allowed_packet=24M` is valid `my.cnf` syntax. You set variables by just putting the `name=value` pair in there.

Comment: ah so this is the right syntax, previously is for old mysql syntax
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=24M
max_connections=300
log-slow-queries
local-infile=0
open_files_limit=3980 

btw if i add safe-show-database, got FAILED message too, is it already changed too?

Comment: I know this is quite old, but doesn't the error log location depend on the settings in my.cnf? If my.cnf fails to load, then there will be no error log.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check mysql logs and error logs to see whats going on with mysql service,if you see no error logs than you can deploy these steps.

Check if there is any running MySQL process

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

If you are able to see any mysql process like below, just kill that process.

```
kill -9 pid
```

Make sure that there is no mysql process running at this point. Restart MySQL.

OR

Try moving the `mysql` config file `/etc/my.cnf` file and restart `mysql`.

```
mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.backup
```

Restart `mysql`.

OR

Try to move the log file named `ib_logfile` in `/var/lib/mysql` and restart `mysql`. Sometimes `mysql` will fail because it face difficulty updating the log file.

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile* /root/
```

Restart and see the results.

```
service mysqld restart
```

You can also remove `ib_logfile` as it will be created automatically after `mysql` restart.

Comment: omg, why all this fuss instead of just opening your error log ??

Comment: @ADM in my case there is no error in the error logs.